# While Retriving the Resource from the Org in VS Code Facing SFDX command Error regarding sfdx.retrive.component

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, vs-code, visualstudiocode, extension

I am trying to retrive the resource from the connected Org in VS Code. While clicking on the retrive button vscode is showing me the error like this:

> **Error running command sfdx.retrieve.component: Node of type empty does not have a parent metadata type node. This is likely caused by the extension that contributes sfdx.retrieve.component.**

Does anybody have idea regarding this error and how can i fix this error in vscode?